# Importing a .props file in .vcxproj generated by qmake

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qmake, vsprops

With a command

```
qmake -tp vc -r
```

I'm generating Visual Studio `.sln` file and a bunch of `.vcxproj` files from corresponding Qt `.pro` file and a bunch of `.pri` files.

I would like those generated `.vcxproj` files to import my own `.props` file. A path to which I can provide to `qmake` or embed it in those `.pro`/`.pri` files.

Is it possible? If so then how?

Since by my research it seems that this can by only done by adding a custom extension (which I would have to write first...) to `mkspecs`...

Comment: I would love to have an answer to this question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by qmake source code, it's not possible. I've looked into `qmake\generators\win32\msbuild_objectmodel.cpp` in both Qt4.8.5 and [latest Qt5 version](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/117880499754b14bbada9646b85feef066d7b959:qmake/generators/win32/msbuild_objectmodel.cpp#L445), and the only Property Sheets that are added by qmake are `Microsoft.Cpp.*.props` (of various kinds):

```
xml << tag("Import")
    << attrTag("Project", "$(UserRootDir)\\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props")
    << attrTag("Condition", "exists('$(UserRootDir)\\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')")
   << closetag()
   << closetag();
```

I have solved this problem by creating a quick Python script, that does the post-processing on the generated *.vcxproj files:

```
for l in fileinput.FileInput('Project.vcxproj', inplace=1):
    print l,
    if 'PropertySheets' in l:
        print '    <Import Project="YourPropertySheets.props" />'
```

Of course, it would be better to patch the qmake with the new functionality, but since there are only three people including you and me that are bothered with this, I believe the hack to be the optimal solution.

Comment: FYI: I ended up crafting custom extensions for MS Build to handle Qt in "native style". They work pretty well and could be further improved in few places but MS Build community support is weak and I don't have that much time myself. But what is missing are some nice item templates which would make it even better. Maybe I will add them at some point as well.